# Targeting only H2s inside a div

Tags: javascript, css

I have a script to create a link list from H2s in the body of a page. I only want the H2s from inside a div called 'page-content'. How can I only use the script below to find those?

```
<script>
        var count = $('pagecontent.h2').size();
        alert(count);
        if (count > 1) {
            $('h1').append('<ul id="subnav">');
            $('h2').each(function(index) { 
                $(this).attr('id', 'subnav-'+index);
                $('#subnav').append('<li><a href="#subnav-'+index+'">'+$(this).text());
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: jQuery selectors are just like CSS, check again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear, ***"div called 'page-content'."*** can be many things, each wiill require a different approach (**[testing code demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/tSj8n/)**):

If `pagecontent` is the **`id`**:

```
<div id="pagecontent">
    <h2>1</h2><h2>2</h2>
</div>
```

Then:

```
var count = $('#pagecontent h2').size(); // 2
```

If `pagecontent` is the **`name` attribute**:

```
<div name="pagecontent">
    <h2>1</h2><h2>2</h2><h2>3</h2>
</div>
```

Then use:

```
 var count = $('div[name="pagecontent"] h2').size(); // 3
```

Or, else, if `pagecontent` is the **`div`'s `class`**:

```
<div class="pagecontent">
    <h2>1</h2><h2>2</h2><h2>3</h2><h2>4</h2>
</div>
```

The way to go is:

```
var count = $('.pagecontent h2').size(); // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Select you h2's like so in jQuery:

```
$('#page-content h2').somefunction()
```